# Keeping gap between hidden elements to avoid jumping position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website and I have a div which is hidden when the page loads, but keeps a small gap between the top header element, and a form.

Under a certain condition, javascript is used to add a class the message div and show a message to the user, after a 5 second timer, the message is then faded out and the classes removed, with another class added to keep the gap between the header element and the form, however, this isn't working, instead when the message div is faded out, the form jumps to the position of where the message was.

Below is my StyleSheet

```
#message
{
    height: 50px;
}

.messageBlank
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.messageError
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff5555;
    border: solid red thin;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Below is my javascript which controls showing and hiding the message box

```
var timer = null; 
var MessageTypeEnum = {"error":1, "workingOrComplete":2}
function showMessage(persistent, message, type)
{
    clearTimeout(timer);
    //$('#message').css({
    //    position:'absolute',
    //    padding: '10px',
    //    left: ($(window).width() - $('#message').outerWidth(true))/2
    //});

    $("#message")
        .hide()
        .html(message);

    //if (type == "error")
    if (type === MessageTypeEnum.error)
    {
        $("#message").addClass("messageError");
    }
    //else if (type == "workingComplete")
    else if (type === MessageTypeEnum.workingOrComplete)
    {
        $("#message").addClass("messageWorkingComplete");
    }

    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
    if (!persistent)
    {
        timer = setTimeout("hideMessage()", 5000);
    }
}

function hideMessage()
{
    $("#message")
        .fadeOut("slow", function()
        {
            $("#message").removeClass("messageError");
            $("#message").removeClass("messageWorkingComplete");
            $("#message").addClass("messageBlank");
        });
}
```

Below is my HTML

```
<body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <a href="http://www.boardiesitsolutions.com" title="Return to Boardies IT Solutions"><img src="../images/header.png" alt="header" /></a>
                <span style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 50px; color: white; top: 0px; position: absolute;">Boardies Bug Reporter</span>
            </header>

            <div id="content">

                <div id="errorToolbox">&nbsp;</div>

                <div id="message" class="messageBlank">&nbsp;</div>

                <form action="javascript:validate();" novalidate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Username: </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" autofocus required placeholder="Username" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password: </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" required placeholder="Password"
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td class="buttonGroup">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                                <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>

            </div>
```

Comment: I've made a JSFiddle with the code you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/wt5Vj/.

Comment: I do not know how to trigger the effects you talk about. Can you please verify if I accurately reproduced your code? I did not know which jQuery library version you use so I included none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep a gap you should use [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) method. For example to hidde element you can do:

```
$("#message").fadeTo( 200, 0, function()...
```

and to show

```
 $("#message").fadeTo( 200, 1);
```

Where `200` is time in ms of how fast your animation should work.

This method will just change `opacity` of element and will keep it original height